# how to limit values in counter in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am following this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RtrRej?p=preview) . here increment and decrement button can be used to set any number. I can click minus button many time to set a negative number. how can I limit this to only a few numbers? such as 0 to 5 only. I mean number should not go below 0 and above 5.

```
export class CustomCounterComponent {

  counterValue = 0;
  @Output() counterChange = new EventEmitter();

  @Input()
  get counter() {
    return this.counterValue;
  }

  set counter(val) {
    this.counterValue = val;
    this.counterChange.emit(this.counterValue);
  }

  decrement() {
    this.counter--;
  }

  increment() {
    this.counter++;
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by limit , you have to put if and else here just to limit

Answer (score 2):

```
decrement() {
    if(this.counter > 0)
        this.counter--;
}

increment() {
    if(this.counter < 5)
        this.counter++;
}
```

Comment: Omg you beat me was writing this :D

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple `if` conditions. [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Trs6a0pSdsCawVigMnXY?p=preview)

```
 decrement() {
    if(this.counter > 0)
      this.counter--;
  }

  increment() {
    if(this.counter <5)
      this.counter++;
  }
```

Comment: @Swoox both answers are given at the same time.  I didn't copy it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via your component'ss typescript or thru your components template

**Typescript**

```
increment(){
if(this.counter < 5){
       this.counter++;
    }
}

decrement(){
    if(this.counter > 0){
       this.counter--;
    }
}
```

**Component**

Check forked [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ulPfQylgmFD2gA1KnlEe?p=preview)

```
<button [disabled]="counter == 0" (click)="decrement()">-</button>
<span>{{counter}}</span>
<button [disabled]="counter == 5" (click)="increment()">+</button>
```